# Using Jquery with dynamically generated id in ADF

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-adf

I use the below code to get the id `p:r:0:abc` to  `p\\:r\\:0\\:abc`

```
function getId(comp) {
  var id = comp.getClientId().split(':').join('\\\\:');
  return id;
}
```

and I am using the generated id for the following

```
$(id).css("background-image", "url('../something.png')");
$(id).slideToggle();
```

it's not changing the background or doing the animation

But if I hard code the id as below its working fine

```
$(`#p\\:r\\:0\\:abc`).css("background-image", "url('../something.png')");
$(`#p\\:r\\:0\\:abc`).slideToggle();
```

Can you advice?

Comment: Why don't you do `comp.getClientId().split(':').join('-')`? That way, you can use `#p-r-0-abc` instead! Or better yet, use `comp.getClientId().replace(/:/g,'-')`! If the `:` change into something else, just use `.replace(/[!"#$%&'\(\)*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, '-')` and you are set!

Comment: The generated id by the framework is 'p:r:0:abc' so i dont think i can change that right?

Comment: The framework creates elements with that id? Please, tell me it doesn't!

Comment: Yes the ID is created as `p:r:0:abc`

Comment: ... wow ... What a terrible idea! `:` is used for pseuso-classes and pseudo-elements... You have no way to control it?

Comment: Nope sadly. Its a pretty old framework (2005) , so maybe it was a different standard then ?

Comment: The standard was different, but the meaning of the `:` character, in CSS, was the same... since it is nearly 10 years old, maybe it's time to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1 too many `\` in your join.

You only need 1 `\` to escape the `:` - `p\:r\:0\:abc`.

```js
var id = "p:r:0:abc".split(':').join('\\\:');
alert($('#' + id).text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b id="p:r:0:abc">TEST</b>
```

Comment: single ? I thought i read it was double backslash? Does it work differently in older version?

Comment: you need \\ to escape \. but one to escape other characters. if your id was `foo\:bar` you would need 3, \\\: 2 for the \ and 1 for `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing id selector `#` while creating selector. It should be:

```
$('#'+id); // id = 'p\\:r\\:0\\:abc'
```

You can rather use attribute equals selector to handle selector with special character:

```
var id= 'p:r:0:abc';
$('[id="'+id+'"]').css("background-image", "url('../something.png')");
$('[id="'+id+'"]').slideToggle();
```

Comment: Don't forget that an `id` selector **only and only** selects 1 element. If you want to keep it the same, you **must** use `eq(0)` after the selector (E.g.:`$('[id="'+id+'"]').eq(0)` or `$('[id="'+id+'"]:eq(0)')`)

Comment: @Sam: What is the value of id after escaping? it should be `p\\:r\\:0\\:abc`

Comment: Thanks it worked . Ya the value after conversion is p\\:r\\:0\\:abc . but it didnt work

Comment: You are missing id selector `#`. Should be `$('#'+id)`

Comment: I tried it earlier it didnt work after adding the hash . I will have a look at it again. thanks.

Comment: @Sam: great. glad it helps :)